# Not able to get lock on synchronized method when accessed using more than one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, elasticsearch, search, synchronization

I have below code where I am testing thread synchronization for elastic search, but somehow I am not able to success in it, can any one let me know where I am going wrong?
If I enable Thread sleep inside 'startThreadProcess' method then everything works fine because it sleeps for certain amount of time period. Which I don't want to, I want to get proper lock for thread without using thread sleep.
but what is happening in above code I have used Executor for pooling threads. There I am running for loop for count 4 so as to initiate 4 threads from pool. so when my thread submitted using executor submit which calls synchronized method and inside that synchronized method I am giving call to other synchronized method from where I am getting total number of count in particular node and proceeding ahead with that count by incrementing to insert new document where my first thread is yet not completed 2nd thread enters and try to get total number of count from the method which is being called from synchronized method so there I am getting wrong count for thread 2 as my first thread will insert 10000 json documents inside node so I am expecting Thread 2 should get count 10000 and then it should process for insert but here my Thread 2 enters in between and get count any random number and start inserting by incrementing from that number which is not expected scenario

```
package com.acn.adt.main;

public class ESTest {

    private static final String dataPath = "C:\\Elastic Search\\Data.json";
    static ESTest esTest = new ESTest();
    private static TransportClient client = null;
    private Properties elasticPro = null;
    private InputStream input = null;

    ElasticSearchCrud esCRUD = null;

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strArray[] = new String[] {"1"};
        esTest.startProcess(strArray);
    }

    public void startProcess(String strArray[]) {
        try {
        input = new FileInputStream(ElasticSearchConstants.ELASTIC_PROPERTIES);
        elasticPro = new Properties();
        //elasticPro.load(ElasticSearchClient.class.getResourceAsStream(ElasticSearchConstants.ELASTIC_PROPERTIES));
        elasticPro.load(input);
        System.out.println(elasticPro.getProperty("homeDir"));

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Settings setting = Settings.builder()
        //.put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "100s")
        .put("cluster.name", elasticPro.getProperty("cluster"))
        //.put("node.name", elasticPro.getProperty("node"))
        //.put("client.transport.sniff", Boolean.valueOf(elasticPro.getProperty("transport.sniff")))
        .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
        .put("cluster.routing.allocation.enable", "all")
        .put("cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance", "always")
        //.put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true)
        .build();

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(setting)
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 
                    Integer.valueOf("9300")));

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time taken for connecting " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((endTime - startTime)));


        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for(int i = 1; i <=4; i++) {

            if(i==1) {
                strArray = new String [] {"1"};
            }else if(i == 2) {
                strArray = new String [] {"1"};
            }else if(i == 3) {
                strArray = new String [] {"1"};
            }else if(i == 4) {
                strArray = new String [] {"1"};
            }

            executorService.execute(new ESThread(esTest,strArray,i));

        }

        }catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public class ESThread implements Runnable {
        private final Object lock = new Object();
        ESTest esTester = null;
        String strArr [] = null;
        int i =0;
        public ESThread(ESTest esTester,String[] strArr,int i)  {
            this.esTester = esTester;
            this.strArr = strArr;
            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Name of Current thread is Thread_"+i);
            synchronized(lock) {
                esTester.startCRUDProcess(strArr);
            }
            System.out.println("Thread_"+i+" done.");
        }
    }

    public void startCRUDProcess(String [] strArr) {

        SearchAPI esSearch = new SearchAPIImpl();
        boolean caseFlg = false;
        String _indexName = "gcindex";
        String _indexType = "gctype";
        String _ids = "501,602,702#@#1,10000,10001";
        String _id = "10000";
        String[] _strIds = new String[] {"10000","9999"};

        System.out.println("Insert Multiple Process is started...");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        try {
            caseFlg = insertMultipleDocument(dataPath,client,_indexName,_indexType);
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            caseFlg = false;
        }

    }

    public synchronized boolean insertMultipleDocument(String dataPath,TransportClient client,String _indexName,String _indexType) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {

        try {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            // we know we get an array from the example data
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse( new FileReader( dataPath ) );

            BulkRequestBuilder bulkDocument = client.prepareBulk();

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Iterator<JSONObject> it = jsonArray.iterator();
            int i = 0;

            i = _getTotalHits(client,_indexName,_indexType);

            System.out.println("Total number of hits inside index = "+_indexName+" of type = "+_indexType+" are : "+i);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            while( it.hasNext() ) {
                i++;
                JSONObject json = it.next();
                System.out.println("Insert document for "+i+": " + json.toJSONString() );   

                // either use client#prepare, or use Requests# to directly build index/delete requests
                bulkDocument.add(client.prepareIndex(_indexName, _indexType, i+"")
                        .setSource(json.toJSONString(), XContentType.JSON )
                        );
            }

            BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkDocument.get();
            if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
                System.out.println("process failures by iterating through each bulk response item : "+bulkResponse.buildFailureMessage());
                return false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("All Documents inserted successfully...");
                /*if(bulkResponse.getItems()!=null) {
                    for(BulkItemResponse response:bulkResponse.getItems()) {
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                        System.out.println(response.getResponse());
                    }
                }*/
                return true;
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while get Multiple Document : " + ex/*, ex*/);
            return false;
        }
    }   

    public synchronized int _getTotalHits(TransportClient client,String _indexName,String _indexType){
        SearchHits hits = null;
        int recCount = 0;
        long totalCount = 0;
        try {
            SearchResponse seacrhResponse = client.prepareSearch(_indexName)
                    .setTypes(_indexType)
                    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                    .get();

            if (seacrhResponse != null) {
                hits = seacrhResponse.getHits();
                totalCount = hits.getTotalHits();
                System.out.println("count = "+totalCount);
            }

            recCount = Integer.parseInt(totalCount+"");

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while search Index : " + ex/*, ex*/);
        }

        return recCount;
    }    


}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to read through. Are you able to reproduce it with less code? I would go through and remove everything that you don't strictly need in order to reproduce the problem, and then state explicitly what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. That will make it much easier to answer your question, which will give you a higher chance of having it answered. (Going through that exercise might even help you solve it yourself!)

Comment: Why don't you save us the headache and post minimum sized code which reproduces the problem?

Comment: okay, will post minimal code

Comment: I have added all details because anybody who would go through will come to know what code used to achieve things

Comment: Unfortunately, details like printlns and commented-out code don't often help, and instead just make it harder to hone in on the actual problem. If you make the code short enough, it'll be self-explanatory. See [mcve] for more details. For instance, it's quite possible that you won't even need json parsing or Elasticsearch at all to reproduce this problem.

Comment: it is not possible to provide minimal as entire code is required to provide the solution

Comment: @yshavit : please check updated minimal code and description

Comment: I think it's harder to read now: still too much code, and a large, unformatted chunk of text. I think you need to spend some time to really get the question down to its core. If it's a threading question, do you really need elastic search? Can you boil it down to just a couple printlns, plus Thread.sleep to simulate the elastic search call? We don't need the minimum code for all of your requirements, just the bit you're having trouble with (ie synchronization). Ideally, the whole thing is just 20-40 lines of code. Did you read the link I mentioned above?

Comment: Also see this link: http://www.sscce.org (an SSCCE is basically the same as an MCVE, though I'm sure there's somebody out there who would get mad at me for saying that ;) )

Comment: @yshavit : what is that http://www.sscce.org/, threre nothing related to my issue.

Comment: That site is to explain how to write a short example that contains only the relevant details. It's not geared towards any one particular issue.

Comment: @yshavit : but now I have updated question with minimal code.